# Going from Webforms to MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm converting a WebForms application into ASP.NET MVC 4 and I would like to make sure that I'm making correct coding choices and assumptions.

1). Is the MVC equivalent of a user control a partial view?

2). In an aspx page you have a control like

```
<asp:Label id="X" runat="server">
```

with the following code in the code behind:

```
X.Visible = some_condition ? true : false;
```

Ok so, for MVC is this code equivalent?

View:

```
<label id="X" style="display: @Model.IsViewable">
```

Model:

```
IsViewable = some_condition ? "inline-block" : "none";
```

Comment: I believe you should sit down and read up on the fundamentals of MVC because it is vastly different than WebForms. To answer your question, the Model should contain no view logic.

Comment: After searching on the placement of business logic, there are a plethora of differing opinions.  You've got anemic data models, thin controllers / fat models, even creating a service class that isn't either a controller or a model.  Its all very confusing.

Comment: Business logic should go in the Model, most sources will tell you to go the thin controller/fat model path. People tend to get worried when you have "God" models that do way too much, when projects get that large then rules can be bent a bit. For your original question though, you should have zero visual aspects in your model and controller, i believe everyone can agree on that. People often use separate data models and view models, the view models can contain validation error messages and such. Your right, it gets very confusing, nothing is set in stone.

Comment: Ok, vesuvious that makes sense.  Thank you for your explanation.  It may be better to have the IsViewable be a bool (like Bob Mac suggested) and have an if statement in the view write the desired style.

Comment: Yup thats a good route, can use Razor in your views to perform such logic.

Comment: Minor nit to pick:  I'd still suggest you conditionally assign classes in your razor according to your bool, and not the style.

Comment: Ok so this is what I think is the best route:  IsViewable is now a bool and my razor looks like this:

`@if(Model.IsViewable){`
`<label id="X" style="display: block">`
`}`

thanks again @vesuvious and Bob-Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Well, kinda, sorta, but no not really. Very different things - a detailed explanation would be lengthy.

2.) Equivalent maybe, but not really a good thing to do.  Your model should contain data only.  But yes, you can use this data in your razor views to conditionally do things including show or not show things.  However, putting the css strings straight into your model data is klunky at best as well as it's usually a good idea to avoid inline styles whenever possible.  IsViewable as a boolean would be better, and you can still handle showing or hiding elements (in a different way).